# Facebook and Twitter Integration with LWUIT 1.4

Tags: facebook, twitter, java-me, lwuit, codenameone

I am developing J2ME app using LWUIT 1.4 API.

I need to integrate with Facebook and Twitter.

How to do it? Is there any source code that I can learn?

Answer (score 2):

LWUIT4IO which is currently only available in the SVN LWUIT trunk ( http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show ) includes basic support for Twitter and is supposed to get Facebook support within a couple of weeks. Twitter support though is read-only since when that was implemented Twitter only had deprecated basic authentication and OAuth 1.x which is problematic (requires MD5 which means export restrictions etc.). 
However, Terrence used a 3rd party library to handle Twitter interaction with LWUIT and has open sourced his work. For more details of what he did see his post here http://terrencebarr.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/beyond-smartphones-source-code-video-released/

[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) has new facebook integration that actually works on both simulator and devices. Twitter integration will be landing soon as well.